# QCompleter with additional result

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcompleter

Need some help.
I have a `QCompleter` with some `QStringList`, for example:

```
QstringList list;
list << "world" << "mouse" << "user";
```

It works fine when user searches in `QLineEdit` for a word from this `list`, but I want to show a changed result. For example: user types `world` and it shows `hello world` in completer popup.

Is it possible? If yes - how?

Comment: Could you explain how do you get `hello` or what relationship do you have? and if you write `mouse`, what should you return?, could you better explain your question.

Comment: @eyllanesc i have a list with cities and want to make completer search only in that list, but as a result show also that cities type:
user types `London`, result shows `town London` , or `village London`, etc.

Comment: From what I understand you have a list ["A", "B", "C"] and you also have another associated list ["A1", "B1", "C1"] and then if you select A it should be displayed A1 Am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, but A1 should be displayed in the popup

Comment: Okay, from what I understand, an element of the first list is typed, in the popup the corresponding element of the second list must be shown, and now my question when selecting an item of the popup that should be shown in the QLineEdit: the element of the first list or the second?

Comment: @eyllanesc second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must place the data in a model, in this case you will use `QStandardItemModel`, on the other hand to modify the popup you must establish a new delegate, and finally so that when you select an item to be shown in the `QLineEdit` you must override the `pathFromIndex()` method :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCompleter>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QAbstractItemView>

class PopupDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        option->text = index.data(Qt::UserRole+1).toString();
    }
};

class CustomCompleter: public QCompleter
{
public:
    using QCompleter::QCompleter;
    QString pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const{
        return index.data(Qt::UserRole+1).toString();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLineEdit w;

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(&w);
    const std::vector<std::pair<QString, QString>> data{ {"London", "town London"},
                                                         {"Moscow", "town Moscow"},
                                                         {"Tokyo", "town Tokyo"}};
    for(const std::pair<QString, QString> & p: data){
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(p.first);
        item->setData(p.second, Qt::UserRole+1);
        model->appendRow(item);
    }
    CustomCompleter *completer = new CustomCompleter(&w);
    completer->setModel(model);

    PopupDelegate *delegate = new PopupDelegate(&w);
    completer->popup()->setItemDelegate(delegate);
    w.setCompleter(completer);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```